# Share and save Image of ImageView?

Tags: android, share

I have app that has two buttons one for sharing a image and one for saving it to memory
save button working perfectly but sharing button not working .

here is the save button :

```
public void exportImage () {
    if (this.mImageDrawableSet == false) {
        this.mSaveImageOnDisplay = true;
        return;
    }

    try {
        final Bitmap bitmap = getImageBitmap();
        if (bitmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        final File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), super.getResources().getString(R.string.config_external_storage_folder));

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        final File img = new File(dir, this.mNode.name + ".png");
        if (img.exists()) {
            img.delete();
        }

        final OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(img);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

        super.getActivity().sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + dir.toString())));
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Wallpaper Saved To, " + img.toString() + "!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and here is the share section :

```
public void shareimage () {
    if (this.mImageDrawableSet == false) {
        this.mApplyImageOnDisplay = true;
        return;
    }

    try {
        final Bitmap bitmap = getImageBitmap();
        if (bitmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }       
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File cachePath = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/DCIM/Camera/image.jpg");

            cachePath.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(cachePath);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
            ostream.close();
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/*");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(cachePath));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share via"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

and nothing is shown on logcat and i just get something wrong toast .
permissions are correct .

logcat

```
02-15 16:10:50.527: W/System.err(2033):     at      android.support.v4.app.Watson.onMenuItemSelected(Watson.java:126)
02-15 16:10:50.539: W/System.err(2033):     at com.actionbarsherlock.ActionBarSherlock.callbackOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlock.java:604)
02-15 16:10:50.539: W/System.err(2033):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:92)
02-15 16:10:50.539: W/System.err(2033):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:204)
02-15 16:10:50.539: W/System.err(2033):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:986)
02-15 16:10:50.539: W/System.err(2033):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
02-15 16:10:50.539: W/System.err(2033):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
02-15 16:10:50.539: W/System.err(2033):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
02-15 16:10:50.539: W/System.err(2033):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:547)
02-15 16:10:50.539: W/System.err(2033):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
02-15 16:10:50.539: W/System.err(2033):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
02-15 16:10:50.539: W/System.err(2033):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
02-15 16:10:50.543: W/System.err(2033):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-15 16:10:50.543: W/System.err(2033):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-15 16:10:50.543: W/System.err(2033):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-15 16:10:50.543: W/System.err(2033):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-15 16:10:50.543: W/System.err(2033):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 16:10:50.543: W/System.err(2033):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-15 16:10:50.543: W/System.err(2033):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-15 16:10:50.551: W/System.err(2033):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-15 16:10:50.551: W/System.err(2033):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-15 16:10:50.551: W/System.err(2033): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-15 16:10:50.555: W/System.err(2033):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-15 16:10:50.555: W/System.err(2033):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-15 16:10:50.555: W/System.err(2033):     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:941)
02-15 16:10:50.559: W/System.err(2033):     ... 23 more
```

Comment: Can you let me know what exactly message app show to you in Toast?

Comment: im getting this "Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again!" wanna number  them to find out which one is showing ?

Comment: this one is showing  catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found it in case anyone needed it
final shareimage()

```
public void shareimage () {
    if (this.mImageDrawableSet == false) {
        this.mApplyImageOnDisplay = true;
        return;
    }

    try {
        final Bitmap bitmap = getImageBitmap();
        if (bitmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again!1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }       
        final File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), super.getResources().getString(R.string.config_external_storage_folder));

        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }

        final File img = new File(dir, this.mNode.name + ".png");
        if (img.exists()) {
            img.delete();
        }
        final OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(img);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/*");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(img));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share via"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something Went Wrong, Please Try Again!2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You use the file ending ".png" and Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG. I think they should match.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that my code is smaller + since it uses `openFileOutput()` method from Context + MODE_WORLD_READABLE for temporary file it doesn't need any permissions:

```
    ImageView iv = (ImageView )adapter.getmCurrentView();
    String fileName = "image.jpg";
    iv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = iv.getDrawingCache();
    try
    {
        FileOutputStream ostream = getActivity().openFileOutput( fileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
        ostream.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Great photo from Poland!");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi,  I'm sharing with you this great picture!");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile( new File( getActivity().getFileStreamPath( fileName).getAbsolutePath())));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share via"));
```

Comment: Nice idea. Unfortunaetly, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE is deprecated in API17. So it may fail soon with newer Andrid version.

Comment: This is no longer supported and generates an exception. Any other way to create a share image from an ImageView?

Answer (score 1):

I am making a wild guess now, but looks like here:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

you have forgot to call

```
root.mkdirs();
```

afterwards. I mean are you sure at that point of your code that your file + directory exists?